# Responsive design for divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have the following HTML code (the number of divs within the .container can vary).
I want to give these a min width, but otherwise these should fill up the whole width of the screen. When the width of the screen is too small (for responsive designs) the divs should simply go on a new line.
It seems simple, but I've been banging my head with gird, flex and even float, but nothing seems to work. Anybody can help without using media queries?

```
<div class="container">
    <div>pippo</div>
    <div>pluto</div>
    <div>paperino</div>
    <div>topolino</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the [reprex]? CSS? There are numerous easy tuts on grid and FBL, what got you off track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `flex-wrap: wrap;` when there was no space for div, div wrap to the next line.

also i use `justify-content: space-between;` to fill up the whole width of the screen

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>pippo</div>
  <div>pluto</div>
  <div>paperino</div>
  <div>topolino</div>
</div>
```